# Rendering image using Multithread

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a ray tracing algorithm, which works with only 1 thread and I am trying to make it work with any number of threads.

My question is, which way can I divide this task among threads.

At first my Instructor told me to just divide the width of the image, for example if I have an 8x8 image, and I want 2 threads to do the task, let thread 1 render 0 to 3 horizontal area ( of course all the way down vertically ) and thread 2 render 4 to 7 horizontal area.

I found this approach to work perfect when both my image length and number of threads are powers of 2, but I have no idea how can I deal with odd number of threads or any number of threads that cant divide width without a reminder.

My approach to this problem was to let threads render the image by alternating, for example if I have an 8x8 image, andlets say if I have 3 threads.

thread 1 renders pixels 0,3,6 in horizontal direction

thread 1 renders pixels 1,4,7 in horizontal direction

thread 1 renders pixels 2,5 in horizontal direction

Sorry that I cant provide all my code, since there are more than 5 files with few hundreds line of code in each one.

Here is the for loops that loop trough horizontal area, and the vertical loop is inside these but I am not going to provide it here.

My Instructor`s suggestion

```
for( int px=(threadNum*(width/nthreads)); px < ((threadNum+1)*(width/nthreads)); ++px )
```

threadNum is the current thread that I am on (meaning thread 0,1,2 and so on)
width is the width of the image
nthreads is the overall number of threads.

My solution to this problem

```
for( int px= threadNum; px< width; px+=nthreads  )
```

I know my question is not so clear, and sorry but I cant provide the whole code here, but basically all I am asking is which way is the best way to divide the rendering of the image among given number of threads ( can be any positive number). Also I want threads to render the image by columns, meaning I cant touch the part of the code which handles vertical rendering.

Thank you, and sorry for chaotic question.

Comment: Dividing won't be a problem since the remaining part covers the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, let me tell you that *under the assumption that the rendering of each pixel is independent from the other pixels*, your task is what in the HPC field is called an "embarassing parallel problem"; that is, a problem that can be efficiently divided between any number of thread (until each thread has a single "unit of work"), without any intercommunication between the processes (which is **very good**).

That said, it doesn't mean that any parallelization scheme is as good as any other. For your specific problem, I would say that the two main factors to keep in mind are **load balancing** and **cache efficiency**.

Load balancing means that you should divide the work among threads in a way that each thread has roughly the same amount of work: in this way you prevent one or more threads from waiting for that one last thread that has to finish it's last job.

E.g.

You have 5 threads and you split your image in 5 big chunks (let's say 5 horizontal strips, but they could be vertical and it wouldn't change the point). Being the problem embarassing parallel, you expect a 5x speedup, and instead you get a meager 1.2x.

The reason *might be* that your image has most of computationally expensive details in the lower part of the image (I know nothing of rendering, but I assume that a reflective object might take far more time to render than a flat empty space), because is composed by a set of polished metal marbles on the floor on an empty frame.

In this scenario, only one thread (the one with the bottom 1/5 of the image) does all the work anyway, while the other 4 remains idling after finishing their brief tasks.

As you can imagine, this isn't a good parallelization: keeping load balancing in mind alone, the best parallelization scheme would be to assign interleaved pixels to each core for them to process, under the (very reasonable) assumption that the complexity of the image would be averaged on each thread (true for natural images, might yield surprises in very very limited scenarios).

With this solution, your image is eavenly distributed among pixels (statistically) and the worst case scenario is N-1 threads waiting for a single thread to compute a single pixel (you wouldn't notice, performance-wise).

To do that you need to cycle over *all pixels* forgetting about lines, in this way (pseudo code, not tested):

```
for(i = thread_num; i < width * height; i+=thread_num)
```

The second factor, **cache efficiency** deals with the way computers are designed, specifically, the fact that they have many layers of cache to speed up computations and prevent the CPUs to starve (remain idle while waiting for data), and accessing data in the "right way" can speed up computations considerably.

It's a *very complex* topic, but in your case, a rule of thumb might be "feeding to each thread *the right amount* of memory will improve the computation" (emphasys on "right amount" intended...).

It means that, even if passing to each thread interleaved pixels is probably the perfect balancing, it's probably the worst possible memory access pattern you could devise, and you should pass "bigger chunks" to them, because this would keep the CPU busy (note: memory aligment comes also heavily into play: if your image has padding after each line keep them multiples of, say, 32 bytes, like some image formats, you should keep it into consideration!!)

Without expanding an already verbose answer to alarming sizes, this is what I would do (I'm assuming the memory of the image is consecutive, without padding between lines!):

1. create a program that splits the image into N consecutive pixels (use a preprocessor constant or a command argument for N, so you can change it!) for each of M threads, like this:

   1111111122222222333333334444444411111111
2. do some profiling for various values of N, stepping from 1 to, let's say, 2048, by powers of two (good values to test might be: 1 to get a base line, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048)
3. find out where the perfect balance is between perfect load balancing (N=1), and best caching (N <= the biggest cache line in your system)
4. **a** try the program on more than one system, and keep the smalles value of N that gives you the best test results among the machines, in order to make your code run fast everywhere (as the caching details vary among systems).
5. **b** If you *really* **really** want to squeeze every cycle out of every system you install your code on, forget step 4a, and create a code that automatically finds out the best value of N by rendering a small test image before tackling the appointed task :)
6. fool around with SIMD instructions (just kidding... sort of :) )

A bit theoretical (and overly long...), but still I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

An alternating division of the columns will probably lead to a suboptimal cache usage. The threads should operate on a larger continuous range of data. By the way, if your image is stored row-wise it would also be better to distribute the rows instead of the columns.

This is one way to divide the data equally with any number of threads:

```
#define min(x,y) (x<y?x:y)
/*...*/
int q = width / nthreads;
int r = width % nthreads;
int w = q + (threadNum < r);
int start = threadNum*q + min(threadNum,r);
for( int px = start; px < start + w; px++ )
  /*...*/
```

The remainder `r` is distributed over the first `r` threads. This is important when calculating the start index for a thread.

For the 8x8 image this would lead to:

- thread 0 renders columns 0-2
- thread 1 renders columns 3-5
- thread 2 renders columns 6-7